# request.query is undefined in Next.js 13 API route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

Here's a simplified version of the code structure I'm using:

In `app/api/events/route.js`:

```js
import Event from "@models/Event";
import { connectToMongoDB } from "@utils/database/connectToMongoDB";

export default async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  const { filterBy, ...filters } = req.query;
  // Rest of the code...
}
```

And following is the implementation of the above endpoint in `app/(root)/page.jsx`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/events?filterBy=status&status=Live`);
  // Rest of the code...
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
- error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'filterBy' of 'request.query' as it is undefined.
```

Here's the request object that I logged to console:

```js
NextRequest [Request] {
  [Symbol(realm)]: {
    settingsObject: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] }
  },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    method: 'GET',
    localURLsOnly: false,
    unsafeRequest: false,
    body: null,
    client: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] },
    reservedClient: null,
    replacesClientId: '',
    window: 'client',
    keepalive: false,
    serviceWorkers: 'all',
    initiator: '',
    destination: '',
    priority: null,
    origin: 'client',
    policyContainer: 'client',
    referrer: 'client',
    referrerPolicy: '',
    mode: 'cors',
    useCORSPreflightFlag: false,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    useCredentials: false,
    cache: 'default',
    redirect: 'follow',
    integrity: '',
    cryptoGraphicsNonceMetadata: '',
    parserMetadata: '',
    reloadNavigation: false,
    historyNavigation: false,
    userActivation: false,
    taintedOrigin: false,
    redirectCount: 0,
    responseTainting: 'basic',
    preventNoCacheCacheControlHeaderModification: false,
    done: false,
    timingAllowFailed: false,
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [Array]
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    url: URL {
      href: 'http://[::1]:3000/api/events?filterBy=status&status=Live',
      origin: 'http://[::1]:3000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: '[::1]:3000',
      hostname: '[::1]',
      port: '3000',
      pathname: '/api/events',
      search: '?filterBy=status&status=Live',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'filterBy' => 'status', 'status' => 'Live' },
      hash: ''
    }
  },
  [Symbol(signal)]: AbortSignal { aborted: false },
  [Symbol(abortController)]: AbortController { signal: AbortSignal { aborted: false } },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(20) {
      'accept' => [Object],
      'accept-encoding' => [Object],
      'accept-language' => [Object],
      'cache-control' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'cookie' => [Object],
      'host' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-platform' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-dest' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-mode' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-site' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-user' => [Object],
      'upgrade-insecure-requests' => [Object],
      'user-agent' => [Object],
      'x-invoke-output' => [Object],
      'x-invoke-path' => [Object],
      'x-invoke-query' => [Object],
      'x-middleware-invoke' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array]
    ]
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookies: RequestCookies { _parsed: [Map], _headers: [HeadersList] },
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    nextUrl: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] },
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/events?filterBy=status&status=Live'
  }
}
```

I'm encountering the issue in my Next.js application when passing query parameters to the API route. I'm using `getServerSideProps` in a Next.js page component and fetching data from an API route, but it seems that the query parameters are not being correctly received on the server side.

I tried using `useEffect` instead of `getServerSideProps` and the issue still persists.

Comment: What makes you think they're not being received correctly? I can see those params in the what you logged. Check https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#extended-nextrequest-and-nextresponse-apis to understand what `req` is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the signature of your route handler is wrong and it can even work at all within the app router because you are trying to apply the same logic that was used in the pages router.

Route handlers must be a named export such as `GET`, `POST` etc. Additionally here's a snippet of a fully working route handler accessing URL search params:

```
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams
  const query = searchParams.get('query')
  // query is "hello" for /api/search?query=hello
}
```

This is all assuming you *actually* use the app router as implied by your paths starting with `/app`.

Comment: Isn't `nextUrl.searchParams` a plain object, per https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request#nexturl? It's instances of `URLSearchParams` that have a `get` method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately the docs you linked are misleading. The `searchParams` object in the `nextUrl` convenience propery is a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object as well and thus a map instead of a raw enumerable object.